# Save WebAPI response as PDF file

Tags: c#, http, pdf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written WebAPI GET method which returns a file, I have checked SoapUI its working well. Now I want call that service and save the file as a PDF in local drive, I'm getting response from service but how I do convert response into file of PDF format?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FileIndex()
{
    try
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://test-server/api/files");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var output= await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]>();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\testpdf.pdf", output);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return View();
}
```

It throws an exception Throwing exception on `var output...`

> Error reading bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'version',
>   line 1, position 11

Response in SoapUI

```
{
   "version":    {
      "major": 1,
      "minor": 1,
      "build": -1,
      "revision": -1,
      "majorRevision": -1,
      "minorRevision": -1
   },
   "content": {"headers":    [
            {
         "key": "Content-Disposition",
         "value": ["attachment; filename=\"About Us.pdf\""]
      },
            {
         "key": "Content-Type",
         "value": ["application/octet-stream"]
      }
   ]},
   "statusCode": 200,
   "reasonPhrase": "OK",
   "headers": [],
   "requestMessage": null,
   "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you run the code above, then? Does the response from the API actually contain data in PDF format already, or does it return something else, and you want to create a PDF document based on that data? It's a bit unclear

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` of the Web API's response? If it's something other than `application/pdf` then you're not actually receiving a PDF document in the response.

Comment: Throwing exception on ``` var output```  "Error reading bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'version', line 1, position 11.". Added response

Comment: That looks like SOAPUI reading the HTTP headers and showing them to you in JSON format? Or is that the actual response body??

Comment: P.S. `catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }` is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding). It stops you from seeing if your code has errors. If you're going to catch an exception, you must at least log the exception details somewhere, so that you can see that errors are occurring, and be able to use the information to diagnose the cause.

Comment: P.P.S. if you vist `https://test-server/api/files` directly in your browser, does it download the file correctly?

Answer (score 4):

I think your main problem is trying to use `ReadAsAsync<byte[]>` from `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` in your `FileIndex()` method:

```cs
var output = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]>();
```

This is intended to work with JSON responses. There are some links erroneously claiming you can make it work with `application/octet-stream` responses by adding the a line to your `WebApiConfig.cs`, such as:

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
```

I believe that advice is flawed, I've never been able to make it work. If you have that line in your project you should remove it and use the following in your `FileIndex()` method instead:

```cs
var output = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Here is a complete console application that consumes the `application/pdf` stream from a Web API method and saves it to disk (in the TestClient/bin/Debug folder next to the TestClient.exe file):

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestClient
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static async Task FileIndex()
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

            var requestUri = "http://localhost:8080/api/files";

            //var requestUri = "https://test-server/api/files";
            //clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            //    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var output = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                //var path = @"E:\testpdf.pdf";
                var path = @"testpdf.pdf";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, output);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileIndex().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a controller I implemented that demonstrates how to return a PDF file to the client with the proper MIME Type and other metadata information:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestServer.Controllers
{
    public class FilesController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
    {
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var fileName = "testpdf.pdf";

                // Where "~/" is the root folder of the Web API server project...
                var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName);

                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(localFilePath);
                var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                // WARNING: Don't use IDisposables or using(){} blocks here.
                // IDisposables would need to exist for the duration of the client download.
                result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(localFilePath));

                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.CreationDate = fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc;
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.ModificationDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.ReadDate = fileInfo.LastAccessTimeUtc;
                result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Use something proper like Serilog to log the exception here...
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString(), ex.Message);
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this code is working but when file saved to disk its showing corrupted, not opening..

Answer (score -1):

You can use this example to explain your need.

```
public void GeneratePdf(string htmlPdf)
{
   var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
   var htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
       var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
       pdfDoc.Open();

       htmlparser.Parse(new StringReader(htmlPdf));
       pdfDoc.Close();

       byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
       File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\file.pdf", bytes);

       memoryStream.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: You wrote "how I do convert response into file of PDF format". You are strange

Comment: 1) I didn't ask the question - look more closely at the usernames! 2) this answer doesn't deal with downloading a PDF document and saving it to disk. What you're doing here is creating a blank PDF document and inserting some HTML into it. Where did you get the idea that HTML was involved? Not everything downloaded from a webserver is HTML. The question is quite explicit that the GET request is supposed to download PDF data, and the problem comes when trying to read that data and store it on disk. That's why your answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @ADyson To be fair to Vladimir, it is a poor quality question. It does ask, with the keyword being **convert** rather than **save** "I'm getting response from service but how I do **convert** response into file of PDF format?"

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that's true, but looking at the actual code, and also the question title which says "save" quite quickly makes clear what the real intent is.